# When .net says "certificate valid", what is it checking?

Tags: x509, x509certificate2

I'm using the [SignedXml.CheckSignature(X509Certificate2, boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148731(v=vs.110).aspx) method. I would like to know what checks are performed when deciding the validity of the certificate. I have verified that the Current User/Not Trusted list is checked. The documentation says it will use the "address book" store, searching by subject key identifier, to build the certificate chain. I imagine this means the Local Machine and Current User certificate stores?

Am I right to think that certificate revocation and signature timestamp are not checked? To do an OCSP check for certificate revocation, am I obliged to use Bouncy Castle?

Answer (score 0):

In the remarks in the [msdn article you link to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148731(v=vs.110).aspx) one finds:

> In version 1.1 of the .NET Framework, the X.509 certificate is not verified.
>
> In version 2.0 and later, the X.509 certificate is verified.
> In version 2.0 and later of the .NET Framework, the CheckSignature method will search the "AddressBook" store for certificates suitable for the verification. For example, if the certificate is referenced by a Subject Key Identifier (SKI), the CheckSignature method will select certificates with this SKI and try them one after another until it can verify the certificate.

Thus, first of all the behavior of that method has changed in different .NET framework versions. So for reproducible results, you had better not count on that method even check the certificate at all.

Furthermore, the formulation *try them one after another until it can verify the certificate* sounds like there just might be the mathematical test whether or not the certificate is signed by its alleged issuer.

Comment: I control the .net framework version, and version 1.1 was a long time ago. I've established that at least the local CTL is checked.

Comment: *I've established that at least the local CTL is checked.* - That matches the quote above. After all, [AddressBook contains data about certificates, CRLs, and CTLs relating to people. Unlike certificates registered in the TrustedPeople container, these certificates are not explicitly trusted.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787544(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/xml/signedxml.cs,b9518cc2212419a2

It checks

- The certificate has no Key Usage extension, or the Key Usage extension has either Digital Signature or Non Repudiation usages enabled
- The certificate chains up to a trusted root authority
- The certificate has not been revoked
- The certificate was not expired when you called this method

  - It doesn't know when the document was signed, so it doesn't answer that question.
- That none of the certificates in the chain are explicitly prohibited by the user or system configuration.